# Return empty object from typed return function

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I'm using peewee module to interact with my db, and created a function to get an entry from DB, and if it doesn't exist, just trying to return empty object.

I tried

```py
@staticmethod
    def fetch_guild_member(guild_id: int, user_id: int) -> GuildMember:
        try:
            guild_member = GuildMember.get(GuildMember.guild_id == guild_id, GuildMember.user_id == user_id)
            return guild_member
        except peewee.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Compiler complains with "Expected type 'GuildMember', got 'None' instead"

How can I define the return object when none was obtained?